# Java String Fix Contractions

Tags: java

Given the following string:

```
"...Cant you, because I cant, I just CANT."
```

How would one go about adding an `'` in all instances of `cant`, while still preserving capitalization?

```
"...Can't you, because I can't, I just CAN'T."
```

Here's what I have so far. It works, but it seems unnecessarily <strike>slow</strike> complex:

```
public static String fix(String line) {
    if (line == null || line.isEmpty()) {
        return line;
    }

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String[] split = line.split(" ");

    for (String word : split) {
        if (word.replaceAll("\\p{P}", "").equalsIgnoreCase("cant")) { // remove punctuation
            while (word.matches("^\\p{P}.*$")) {  // starts with punctuation
                builder.append(word.charAt(0));
                word = word.substring(1);
            }
            builder.append(word.substring(0, 3)); // can
            builder.append("'");                  // '
            builder.append(word.substring(3));    // t
        } else {
            builder.append(word);
        }

        builder.append(" ");
    }

    return builder.toString().trim();
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that this solution is slow?  Have you tried timing it?  It seems fast enough when I run it.

Comment: I just think there's too much going on for such a simple task. From the looks of it, a regex is the best solution to this problem. EDIT: changed "slow" to "complex" in original post :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case insensitive regex replacement with capture groups on the entire line should be faster:

```
public static String fix(String line) {
    if (line == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return line.replaceAll("(?i)\\b(can)(t)\\b", "$1'$2");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself which steps in your algorithm are really required. In the end, you are **only** looking for all occurrences of the string "cant" (where case doesn't matter). So, why are you splitting up the line. Why are you matching stuff?